# python BeautifulSoup soup.findAll(), how to make search result match

Tags: python

I recent learned BeautifulSoup and as an exercise , I want to use BeautifulSoup to read and extract company and location information from job posting.here is my code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url="http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=hadoop&start=50"
html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
company=soup.findAll("span",{"class":"company"})
location=soup.findAll("span",{"class":"location"})

# for c in company:
#   print c.text
# print 
# for l in location:
#   print l.text

print len(company)
print len(location)
```

I found the length of company and location are not same. So I don't know which (company, location) pair is incomplete. How can I make them match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over search results block and *get the company-location pairs for each block*:

```
for result in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"}):  # or soup.select("div.result")
    company = result.find("span", {"class": "company"}).get_text(strip=True)
    location = result.find("span", {"class": "location"}).get_text(strip=True)

    print(company, location)
```

You should also switch to [`BeautifulSoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), the version you are using is quite old:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And replace:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
```

with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

The code above prints:

```
(u'PsiNapse', u'San Mateo, CA')
(u'Videology', u'Baltimore, MD')
(u'Charles Schwab', u'Lone Tree, CO')
(u'Cognizant', u'Dover, NH')
...
(u'Concur', u'Bellevue, WA')
```